# pylatex tex file generation in NoEscape container

Tags: python-3.x, latex, pylatex

i want to create PDF`s via Python 3.7.9 and Pylatex 1.4.1. I dont know if i encountered a bug.

I try to generate the following formula in the NoEscape container from Pylatex:

```
from pylatex import Document, Section, Math
from pylatex.utils import NoEscape

doc = Document('basic')
section = Section("Section1")

math = NoEscape("$g(10)=1\times 3\times 7\times 9 = 189$")

section.append(math)

doc.append(section)

doc.generate_pdf(clean_tex=False)
```

The first output from Pylatex is a .tex file. Pylatex generates the following code with this code snippet:

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage{lmodern}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{lastpage}%
%
%
%
\begin{document}%
\normalsize%
\section{Section1}%
\label{sec:Section1}%
$g(10)=1    imes 3  imes 7  imes 9 = 189$

%
\end{document}
```

The \times is allways just imes.

The correct output would be:

```
$g(10)=1\times 3\times 7\times 9 = 189$
```

Anyone know a solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the ` \\`  is an escape character so you probably need ` \\\` as is usualy for python strings.

Comment: also, i am not sure what the purpose of `Math` is on the first line as it is not used... did you mean this ?

Comment: @D.L the Math in the first line has no purpose in this example. i forgot to remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `\` is an escape character, in fact `\t` is the tab.

this applies to strings in python:

```py
# \ on its own is an escape character.
s = "$g(10)=1\times 3\times 7\times 9 = 189$"
print(s)

# \\ this will work
s = "$g(10)=1\\times 3\\times 7\\times 9 = 189$"
print(s)
```

result:

```
$g(10)=1    imes 3  imes 7  imes 9 = 189$
$g(10)=1\times 3\times 7\times 9 = 189$
```